# Extract server name from UNC path using Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a rather large spreadsheet in which I have a column dedicated to UNC paths. I have been asked to extract only the server names from those paths for auditing purposes. I tinkered a while and think I am close but can't seem to get just what I need...

`\servername\path\path`

My most successful formula is this:
`=MID(U5,FIND("\",U5)+2,SEARCH("\",U5,FIND("\",U5)+2))`

It returns: "servername\pat". Suggestions on formula options I might use? If I could get Excel to differentiate between "\" and "\", I think life would be easier...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming UNC names in the format of "\servername\sharename\path\filename" in cell D2, the following formula returns "servername":

```
=MID(D2, 3, FIND("\",D2,3)-3)
```

I did hard code the 3 for starting position as the UNC spec states that it starts with \ (at least the one I found). If you have a variable start, I would split the formula into 2 cells to find the start position and use it for the 3/-3 entries in this formula.

Comment: This worked like a champ @Martin. In the process I also found there was a leading space at the beginning of the UNC path which threw off the starting position. I added TRIM(D2) into the formula before copying the formula to the rest of the sheet. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. TRIM is usually a good idea in Excel forumlas as copy/paste often seems to catch extra spaces.